# Firebase Listening for Collection Changes - Costs

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I've got a collection with around 1000 documents within it. I have a listener setup on this collection to look for changes. This listener is very similar to this:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen#listen_to_multiple_documents_in_a_collection

```
db.collection("cities").where("state", "==", "CA")
    .onSnapshot(function(querySnapshot) {
        var cities = [];
        querySnapshot.forEach(function(doc) {
            cities.push(doc.data().name);
        });
        console.log("Current cities in CA: ", cities.join(", "));
    });
```

However, there is also this code sample that listens to changes between snapshots: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen#view_changes_between_snapshots

```
db.collection("cities").where("state", "==", "CA")
    .onSnapshot(function(snapshot) {
        snapshot.docChanges().forEach(function(change) {
            if (change.type === "added") {
                console.log("New city: ", change.doc.data());
            }
            if (change.type === "modified") {
                console.log("Modified city: ", change.doc.data());
            }
            if (change.type === "removed") {
                console.log("Removed city: ", change.doc.data());
            }
        });
    });
```

My question is, is there really any difference between these two implementation when it comes to the data that is transferred over the wire. In my example I have 1000 documents in a collection. After getting the initial 1000 document, if one document changes, then how much data is sent **over the network** for each of these implementations? 1 document? Or 1000?

Normally, I would check the Chrome Developer Tools Network tab to see the payload. If anyone knows how to find the equivalent info for this streamed data, that would be great too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cloud Firestore efficiently sends changes over the wire, and the local client constructs the snapshots containing the updated state of the world. In your example, a change of a single document would result in a single document being sent over the wire and you would be charged for a single document read (per connected client, obviously).

Comment: I figured that might be the case. So as far as performance hits go... the network cost is low, but the client has to hold a copy of the snapshot, which in my case has 1k documents. Any hints on how to debug/observe these network transfers? The network tab payload is filled with strange array of numbers.